# ImportHTML Pulling Through Text As Number In Google Sheets

Tags: html, google-sheets, import

I am scraping data from a website for a spreadsheet I'm putting together. I have used the same formulae to pull the same data from multiple different pages of the website however I have stumbled across a page where it has stopped pulling through correctly.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1041JPTfPYTzVaSAmA4e1UMsUn2gRi3lE1-GaMImM8o4/edit?usp=sharing

Above is a link to show the problem I'm having. A-D is pulling through exactly as I want. F to I is pulling the column headers and nothing else. By removing the condition in the Query I can get it to pull through in K to N however it only pulls through the 3 number values in the 4th column and is not pulling through values about 950 that are written as 1K, 2K etc.

I can't seem to put any conditions on the query solely for this specific page. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this web page, despite all surface appearances, somehow different?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. SO is a plattform for specific coding issues. It is uclear to me what specific issue you have and as such I will flag the queston for closure. A link to document has no value for SO as the link might change and as such the question would hold no further value to the community. I dont see, how we are supposed to help you. You missing to many details and clarity on a specific coding issue.

Comment: Seriously? Someone has responded answering my question and helping me out?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://www.futbin.com/players?page=1&version=all_nif&club=5&sort=ps_price&order=asc",
 "table", 1)),
 "select * where Col5 <> '0'"))
```